Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{5x^2+1}dx$ using the golden ratio $\phi$?
I. Data
Given the following integrals, we have the nice evaluations using  short polylogarithm ladders,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{2x^2+1}dx= \frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\;3\pi^2}{32}-\frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(\alpha_2)}2 + \frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(-\alpha_2^2)}8 -\frac{\pi}4\arccos\sqrt{\frac23} \right)$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{3x^2+1}dx= \frac1{\sqrt3}\left(\frac{\;3\pi^2}{32}-\frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(\alpha_3)}2 + \frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(-\alpha_3^2)}8 -\frac{\pi}4\arccos\sqrt{\frac34} \right)$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{5x^2+1}dx= \frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\frac{\;3\pi^2}{32}-\frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(\alpha_5)}2 + \frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(-\alpha_5^2)}8 -\frac{\pi}4\arccos\sqrt{\frac56} \right)$$
and so on, and where,
\begin{align}
\alpha_2 &= (1-\sqrt2)^2\\
\alpha_3 &= \; 2-\sqrt3\\
\alpha_5 &= \left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^2 = \frac1{\phi^2}
\end{align}
which involve the fundamental units $U_2, U_3, U_5$ (though not for $\alpha_n$ with $n>5$). I noticed the second integral has a much simpler expression,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{3x^2+1}dx= \frac{4\operatorname{Li_2}(\alpha_3) + \ln^2(\alpha_3)}{8\sqrt3}$$
which is also discussed here. I haven't found simpler versions for the other two, but to get rid of the $\operatorname{Li}_2(-\alpha_n^2)$ term, one can use the functional equation,
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z^2)+\operatorname{Li}_2(-z^2) = \dfrac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2(z^4)$$
in this post and have an alternative ladder using $\operatorname{Li}_2(z^k)$ for $k = 1,2,4$ with only positive $z$.

II. Question
So in general, given,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{nx^2+1}dx \overset{\color{red}?}= \frac1{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{3\pi^2}{32}-\frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(\alpha_n)}2 + \frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(-\alpha_n^2)}8 -\frac{\pi}4\arccos\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \right)$$
where,
$$\alpha_n = \frac{n-\sqrt{n}}{n+\sqrt{n}}$$
is the proposed evaluation true for all integer $n>0$?

(Update:)  From FDP's answer, we find the proposed formula is equivalent to,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{nx^2+1}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(\alpha_n)}2 + \frac{\operatorname{Li_2}(-\alpha_n^2)}8 + \frac{\pi}4\arctan\sqrt{n}\right)$$
which seems to be the more natural form since $\dfrac{\pi^2}{32}$ is just the first case $n=1$,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2+1}dx = \frac{\pi^2}{32}$$
and appears often enough to have an OEIS entry.

The answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4973311/186817 could be extented to n>0 integer.

Numerically your formula seems good. I have checked numerically for n=1 to n=100

@FDP If I see patterns or symmetry in my research, while it is no guarantee, it does give one confidence that it is in the right track. Feel free to adapt your answer to this one, and I will accept it. At first, the lack of $\arccos(z)$ in your answer gave me some difficulty, but I found a way around it.

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{1+nx^2}dx\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Big[\arctan\left(x\sqrt{n}\right)\arctan x\Big]_0^1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^1\frac{\arctan\left(x\sqrt{n}\right)}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{\pi\arctan(\sqrt{n})}{4\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^1\frac{\arctan\left(x\sqrt{n}\right)}{1+x^2}dx\\
F(a)&=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan\left(ax\right)}{1+x^2}dx\\
F^\prime(a)&=\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2x^2)}dx\\
&=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+a^2}\right)}{2(1-a^2)}\\
J&=\frac{\pi\arctan(\sqrt{n})}{4\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+a^2}\right)}{1-a^2}da\\
&\overset{z=\frac{1-a}{1+a}}=\frac{\pi\arctan(\sqrt{n})}{4\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}}^1\frac{\ln(1+z)}{z}dz+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{n}}\underbrace{\int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}}^1\frac{\ln(1+z^2)}{z}dz}_{w=z^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi\arctan(\sqrt{n})}{4\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}}^1\frac{\ln(1+z)}{z}dz+\frac{1}{8\sqrt{n}}\int_{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right)^2}^1\frac{\ln(1+w)}wdw\\
&=\frac{\pi\arctan(\sqrt{n})}{4\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(\text{Li}_2\left(-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)+\\&\frac{1}{8\sqrt{n}}\left(\text{Li}\left(-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)\\
J&=\\&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{\pi\arctan(\sqrt{n})}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac12\text{Li}_2\left(-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)+\frac18\text{Li}\left(-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\right)\right)
\end{align}
Since,
\begin{align}\arctan(u)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}}\right)\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}\boxed{J=\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{3\pi^2}{32}-\frac12\text{Li}_2\left(-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)+\frac18\text{Li}\left(-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}\arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)\right)}\end{align}

Great! You made some changes though. You have $\operatorname{Li_2}(-z_n)$ and $\operatorname{Li_2}(-z_n^2)$ where, since $(1-\sqrt{n})<0$, then $-z_n = +\alpha_n$. Nice!

Changes are aesthetic!

I’m all for aesthetics.

We have, \begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\arccos(x)}{nx^2+1} &=;;{_3F_2}\big(\tfrac12,1,1;\tfrac32,\tfrac32;-n\big)\
\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin(x)}{nx^2+1} &=-,{_3F_2}\big(\tfrac12,1,1;\tfrac32,\tfrac32;-n\big)+\frac{\pi\arctan(\sqrt{n})}{2\sqrt{n}}
\end{align} Do you suppose the integral with $\arctan(x)$ has a generalized hypergeometric formula $_pF_q$ as well?

@TitoPiezasIII : I don't know,.
